# neo4j 3.4.0 ubuntu: could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint

Tags: neo4j

I downloaded neo4j 3.4.0 Community edition on Ubuntu 16.04 and installed it. 
I launched it successfully once with command `./neo4j console` 
But after I restarted the system, I used the same command `./neo4j console` in `/bin/`, there is an error: could not find or load main class org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: what is your java version ? is it superior to 8 ?

Answer (score 0):

the neo4j have been based on java. please check jdk path in env.

Comment: Already done that. Before I restarted Ubuntu, neo4j worked fine. But after I did that  neo4j could not start properly.

Comment: maybe java path will be set while neo4j install. but after restart, you should check the java path that is same the path before restart.

Answer (score 0):

After trying many things (and no success).

I reinstalled the app by deleting `~/.configs/Neo4j-desktop` and running again the Appimage file.

consider by this action you will lose license-key (and if you use Appimage version also all Db-data) so backup first if you have important data.